# forbidden empty user agent, but allow it for some specific domain, by using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent

I want to block the empty user agent, but in the scripts of the website, there are some snippets use the file_get_contents function, which will be blocked as well. I tried to add header to the file_get_contents, but it was not good. So I tried to use htaccess to bypass the localhost.

Here is the rule in htaccess:

```
#Block empty User-Agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://(.*\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

But it does not wok. How should I change? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After edit and test for several times, I make it worked:

```
#Block empty User-Agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://(.*\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/url [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Also tried:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(127\.0\.0\.1|localhost) [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1
```

Doesnot help. Only the REQUEST_URI works.